# Check subgraph based in vertex attributes(name) and edges colors/weight

Tags: r, igraph, subgraph

Is there some way to check in R/igraph if a graph m is subgraph of another graph g, based on attributes vertices (name) and weight or colors of the edges?

The funtcion `is_subgraphic_isomomorphic_to(m,g, method=vf2)` does not work, because it uses vertex id (and I need to use attributes(name/color))

example: 
[graph m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcwVa.png)

[graph g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JLXX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** `is_subgraphic_isomomorphic_to(m,g, method=vf2)` uses colors (vertex/edge), and i need to use both the names of the vertices and weight/colors edges, as in the example figures.